# Sample Metafont source for one character

Tags: sourcecode, metafont, computer-modern

I would just like to look at the Metafont source code for the lower-case 'a' in the Computer Modern font. Where could I find that? Or even better, if that source could be the answer to this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is not really well-defined, I'm afraid.

One answer is [romanl.mf](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/knuth/dist/cm/romanl.mf), right at the top of the file, but that file is run by being called by other files.  You could start higher up the call stack with [cmr10.mf](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/knuth/dist/cm/cmr10.mf), but even there you need to understand Knuth's macro definitions to be able to read what is happening.  So basically it is one of those cases where to understand a small part you need to have at least a rough understanding of the entire system.

Comment: Actually, romanl.mf is just about what I was interested in seeing. I'm reading an introduction to Metafont and wanted to see some use of it in something production-level it's actually used to make. Not that I understand it all, of course. Thanks!